# equivilent line of code not working in a different function

Tags: python

I have the following function that randomly gives out stats to skills. it works as I expect it to.

```
def randstat(level): 
    from random import randint
    points = randint(10,max(20,5*level))

    # set all our minimums to zero
    stats = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

    for i in range(1, points):
        stat = randint(0, len(stats)-1); # pick a random stat to increment
        stats[stat] += 1

    # extract the stats back out of our array
    agility = stats[0]
    stamina = stats[1]
    strength = stats[2]
    vitality = stats[3]
    intelligence = stats[4]
```

However I want to simplify `stat = randint(0, len(stats)-1);` to `stat = randlist(stats)` using another function I already have:

```
def randlist(list):
    from random import randint
    return(list[randint(0,len(list)-1)])
```

This gives me an error:
exeptions.indexError:list index is out of range
 Any ideas why it does this when I pretty much have the exact same line of code just in another function?
Probably a really simple thing i'm overlooking. thanks in advance anyway.

Comment: What's the error you are getting?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name; and you should use `random.choice` instead of `randint`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra lookup in the `randlist` function, and you end up trying to do something like this:

```
stats[stats[stat]] += 1
```

fix this by removing the extraneous `list[]` from `randlist`, so you just return the random index (rather than the value):

```
def randlist(list):
    return randint(0, len(list)-1)
```

but, do consider using a different data structure as in [Burhan Khalid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472169/equivilent-line-of-code-not-working-in-a-different-function/22472460#22472460). Python best practice is to avoid index arithmetic whenever you can - doing so tends to lead to code that is easier to read and maintain, and as a nice bonus, it's often shorter.

Answer (score 0):

> However I want to simplify stat = randint(0, len(stats)-1); to stat =
>   randlist(stats)

You can simplify it in your method by using `random.choice`.  There were some other issues with your code, here is an improved version, that uses a dictionary for the stats:

```
import random

def randstat(level): 
    points = random.randint(10,max(20,5*level))
    stats = {'agility': 0,
             'stamina': 0,
             'strength': 0,
             'vitality': 0,
             'intelligence': 0}

    for i in range(1, points):
        stat = random.choice(stats.keys()) # pick a random stat to increment
        stats[stat] += 1

    return stats
```